# How do I check if a Socket is currently connected in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to find out whether a Java TCP Socket is *currently* connected, the following just seems to tell me whether the socket has been connected at some point - not whether it is currently still connected.

```
socket.isConnected();
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969866/java-detect-lost-connection

Comment: And another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485855/how-do-you-handle-socket-disconnecting-in-java

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17889321/207421).

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you have some level of control over the protocol, I'm a big fan of sending heartbeats to verify that a connection is active.  It's proven to be the most fail proof method and will often give you the quickest notification when a connection has been broken.

TCP keepalives will work, but what if the remote host is suddenly powered off?  TCP can take a long time to timeout.  On the other hand, if you have logic in your app that expects a heartbeat reply every x seconds, the first time you don't get them you know the connection no longer works, either by a network or a server issue on the remote side.

See [Do I need to heartbeat to keep a TCP connection open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865987/do-i-need-to-heartbeat-to-keep-a-tcp-connection-open) for more discussion.