# how to detect (shutdowninput in read)

Tags: java, android, socket.io, inputstream, bufferedreader

In my Android app when closing the connection(like turning of WiFi) I'm getting an infinite number of this log message `[cds] shutdowninput in read` which interrupts my app and makes it do tons of unnecessary input checking, I'm using java socket programming and I tried to check for that issue by calling `isInputShutdown()` but got nothing, that how I am trying:

```
public String getServerResponse() throws Exception{

      while(true){
                  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                  if(xbmc_socket.isInputShutdown()){
                     return "stopped";
                  }else{
                     //continue(and that's what it always doing)
                  }
       }
}
```

Comment: What happens inside the 'continue' part? And why are you creating the BufferedReader inside the loop?

Comment: no no just very simple processing and it doesn't affect the whole process

Comment: Do you store the lines you read into a data structure?

Comment: found an answer to this one?

Comment: @RonanDejhero I added the answer I reached, have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was because I'm declaring `BufferedReader` as a **local** variable (as appears in my code in the question), and that led to an opened socket in the end of the connection either this connection ended from my side or from the other side.

Hence, to overcome this problem, I declared the `BufferedReader` as a **global** variable, which enabled me to handle it when connection closed, like closing the socket manually or doing whatever fits my app the best:

```
public BufferedReader in;
public String getServerResponse() throws Exception{
  while(true){
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      // the rest of the code
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
ALready solved it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240694/java-socket-api-how-to-tell-if-a-connection-has-been-closed ... without the need to capture that, but still will give it a try

Comment: @RonanDejhero great, I think also you can merge the two answers together.