# ServerSocket detecting disconnection of client

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am using the below code for my Server to continue listening to Client message once it's become connected.

While listening, I wanted to detect if the Client become disconnected when `read` value becomes `-1` and finished the `WhileLoop`.

```
private volatile boolean isConnected = true;
//....
while(isConnected){ //Whe it comes to false then Receiving Message is Done.
    try {
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000); //Timeout is 10 Seconds
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream inputS = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int read = inputS.read(buffer);
        String msgData = new String(buffer,0,read);

        //Detect here when client become disconnected
        if(read == -1){ //Client become disconnected
            isConnected = false;
            Log.w(TAG,"Client is no longer Connected!");
        }else{
            isConnected = true;
            Log.w(TAG,"Client Still Connected...");
        }

        //....
    }catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Failed to Receive message from Client, SocketException occured => " + e.toString());
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Failed to Receive message from Client, IOException occured => " + e.toString());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Failed to Receive message from Client, Exception occured => " + e.toString());
    }           
}

Log.w(TAG, "Receiving Message is Done.");
```

The above code works on receiving message but I'm having problem detecting when the client become disconnected.

When the client become disconnected, an Exception is occured whith the following error: `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=256; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1` and the `WhileLoop` is not breaking as expected to be done.

I am assuming that when the client become disconnected then this condition will occured `if(read == -1){....}`.

I just found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240694/java-socket-api-how-to-tell-if-a-connection-has-been-closed) while searching and the answer of **EJP** give me the best solution on `read() returns -1` , but I'm just starting on `ServerSocket` so I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: You should not construct the string if read returns -1. I would simply move the string construction to the else branch if `if(read == -1)` .

Comment: @Fildor - WTF, LOL, is that what I'm just doing wrong? I tried it and guest what? It works!!!

Comment: @Fildor - How about making it Answer instead of Comment? I am happy to mark is as a correct answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String msgData = new String(buffer,0,read);`

If `read`is -1 it will throw an Exception. I'd totally expect that.
Just move that line to your `else` branch where you check read for -1 so the string will only be constructed when there is actually data.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-

> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - If the offset and the length arguments index characters outside the bounds of the bytes array

-1 length **is** outside of bounds :)