# Connection pool to tcp server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to implement a tcp client based on classic `I/O`. In order to reduce negotioation latency I decided to create a connection pool to the server which looks like this:

```
BlockingQueue<Socket> connections = //
```

Every time a thread trying to communicate with the server it does the following:

```
Socket s = null;
try{
    Socket s = connections.take();
    if(s.isClosed())
       s = //create a new connection
    //send data to the server
} finally { 
    if(!connections.offer(s))
        throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

I'm not sure if it's common to do like this. At least I have not heard about such an approach. Can someone suggest something that's more common.

Comment: `isClosed()` doesn't do what you think it does, but otherwise this is a standard approach,

Comment: @EJP Did not quite understand. Documentation says that it returns if a `Socket` has been closed. What's wrong?

Comment: @EJP Ah... u mean to replace it with `isConnected()`?

Comment: The only way a `Socket` can be closed is if you closed it, in which case it shouldn't be in the connection pool at all. It doesn't tell you whether the *connection* has been closed. `isConnected()` is no improvement. You should only put the socket back in the pool if there weren't any problems with it, not in a `finally` block.

Comment: If you want to know how to tell if the connection has been closed see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240694/java-socket-api-how-to-tell-if-a-connection-has-been-closed